# Metro Builder: SyntaxError: Unexpected token = after upgrading to React Native 0.65.1

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, metro-bundler

Today [I updated to React Native Version 0.65.1](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.64.2&to=0.65.1).
After that I was unable to Start the Metro Server

I am now receiving following error message while building a Release .apk:

```
    node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:350
  processRequest = (req, res, next) => {
                 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED
```

I've tried:

- Updating Node
- Cleaning Project
- Restarting Computer

This is the snippet from the Metro Server Node Module

```
processRequest = (req, res, next) => {
    this._processRequest(req, res, next).catch(next);
  };
```

*Additional Information:
I am using a MacBook Pro with macOS Big Sur 11.5.2*

**Thanks everyone**

Comment: I am getting same issue, did you fixed the issue @Maaax ?

Comment: @Ravi Yes, mithunSalinda's Answer worked for me. It seems like it has something to do with node and nodes caching. After following the steps and updating Node again, I was even able to upgrade React Native again without any further problems.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just my two cents:
I had the same problem. My problem was due to NVM. I used node version 14 for the current project but my default version was node 10. And metro server opened in a new terminal that didn't use the current node but the default one. Fixed it by setting node version to 14.

Fix:
`nvm alias default v14.17.0`

Comment: not helped for me (

Comment: OMG! That is nifty.

Answer (score 1):

I have used react native 0.66 after i downgraded into 0.64, this worked for me.

1. downgrade react into 0.64.0
2. clear node cache & gradle clean
3. npm install

Comment: Downgrading is not an option when you are upgrading. How is this a serious answer?

Answer (score 1):

I have a new React Native project on v0.66 and have encountered this but was able to fix it without downgrading.

So, I use nvm to manage my node versions and I'm on v16.13.0 currently, which should be ok, but it seems I also had node and yarn installed through brew. The node version in brew was v13.10.1.

To fix this:

1. Uninstall node and yarn from brew

`brew uninstall yarn`

`brew uninstall node`

2. Reinstall yarn globally through npm

`npm install --global yarn`

and it works  hopefully this helps someone else

Answer (score 1):

I am also using React Native latest version

> "react": "17.0.2",
> "react-native": "0.66.2"

The problem in my system was the node version i was using `node@10` and just using nvm i used default node version as `node@14`, which worked for me.

```
nvm use 14
```

Answer (score 0):

For iOS only open xcode under "Build Phase" -> "Bundle React Native code and images" modify NODE_BINARY to absolute path of your nvm setting.

```
export NODE_BINARY=node
...
```

Find current absolute path of nvm node version using:

```
nvm use <your_version_here>
which node
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a new project with react 17 and react native 0.68, the fix for me was updating npm using this command:

> npm install -g npm@latest

And updating nodejs from the [official page](https://nodejs.org/) (just downloading and installing the LTS version).